# How do I stop community content in specific languages from appearing in the new Steam library?

Tags: steam

The Steam Library has a display of the latest community content beneath the information for a game. The problem is loads of this is in Russian, Chinese, Japanese, Korean and other languages that I can't read and am not interested in.

Is there a way to filter out content in specific languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community content isn't filtered by language on the Workshop, so I don't think it's possible to do that.

You can try and ask about it or suggest this feature to the developers [here](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks)

Comment: Welcome to the site Leo! "This isn't possible" is a perfectly valid answer on Arqade, so I've gone ahead and removed your sentence about how you can't comment yet. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, and happy to be here among my ken